# Can I configure my Macbook to unmount all external drives when I close the lid?

Tags: macbook-pro, time-machine, sleep-wake, external-disk

I have a new 13" Macbook Pro running Mavericks. This computer is connected to an external USB drive which I use for my Time Machine backups and for external storage Time Machine backups occur a few times per day and the drive is largely inactive for most of the day.

When I am rushing to a meeting, to the server room or I'm heading home at the end of the day, I would like to do the following:

1. Close the lid on my Macbook, quickly.
2. Have the Mac automatically unmount all external drives, as quickly as possible, and forcibly if required. I'm willing to wait a few seconds for the all of lights to turn off.

Is there a way to get the computer to automatically unmount all external drives as soon as I close the lid on my Mac?

Currently if I forget to unmount the external drives, my Mac chastises me later with the error "The disk was not ejected properly. If possible, always eject a disk before unplugging it or turning it off."

I know it is best practice to always unmount a disk cleanly before removing the disk interface, but I'm looking for an automated solution. I am not very concerned if one Time Machine backup image is interrupted or corrupted, as one of the next subsequent backups will work and I very rarely ever need to restore from backup. Since the filesystem is a journaling filesystem, the journal transparently takes care of many other filesystem corruption errors.

Comment: Since logging out of your account unmounts all drives, is there a significant downside to just logging out? Also, I believe the OS flushes all filesystem IO writes, so the chance of an actual problem with ejection during sleep seems quite low to me - doubly so for journaled filesystems.

Answer (score 8):

There are a number of apps that can run scripts on sleep:

- [SleepWatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/) — simple yet effective.
- [Scenario](http://www.lagentesoft.com/scenario/index.html) — can also run scripts at other times such as after wake.
- [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/) — more customisable, lets you run scripts after many different events.

A bash script such as the following will unmount all specified disks:

```
VOLUMES="/Volumes/drive1 /Volumes/drive2 /Volumes/drive3"
for volume in $VOLUMES ; do [ -d $volume ] && umount -f $volume done
```

To unmount all volumes except `/`:

```
umount -A
```

or more cleanly…

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to eject (every disk whose ejectable is true)'
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option is [Jettison](http://www.stclairsoft.com/Jettison/) (available through the App Store) - that's what I've been using for a couple of months now and haven't had any problems at all.  It recently gained the option of automatically remounting still-connected disks when you wake from sleep.

The newer v1.3.0 (direct download only - I assume it's on its way to the App Store) costs more and they explain why this is in their FAQ.

If I read that correctly, one could buy the App Store version for two dollars and then upgrade to the direct-download version for free, but I haven't confirmed or tried this.

Not exactly expensive at either price, but not free like the SleepWatcher option seems to be.

Answer (score 4):

I'll elaborate on @grgarside's answer.

I'm using SleepWatcher

1. Install from ports:

   ```
   sudo port install sleepwatcher
   ```
2. Read the manual at `/opt/local/share/doc/sleepwatcher/ReadMe.rtf` and via `man sleepwatcher`. Read this old Machint from Macworld: [Cure an insomniac Mac with SleepWatcher System](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2006022212342874). According to the Machint I can simply add code to `~/.sleep` and `~/.wakeup` , or to the global files `/etc/rc.sleep` & `/etc/rc.wakeup`.
3. Place the following code in `~/.sleep`:

   ```
   osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to eject (every disk whose ejectable is true)'
   ```
4. Activate sleepwatcher. Change `<key>Disabled</key><true/>` to `<key>Disabled</key><false/>`.

   ```
   sudo vim /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.sleepwatcher.plist
   sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.sleepwatcher.plist
   sudo launchctl list | grep sleepwatcher
   ```
5. Verify:

   ```
   ps aux |grep [s]leepwatcher
   root              421   0.0  0.0  2459568   1012   ??  Ss    2:45PM   0:00.00 /opt/local/bin/daemondo --label=sleepwatcher --start-cmd /opt/local/sbin/sleepwatcher --verbose --sleep /opt/local/etc/rc.sleep --wakeup /opt/local/etc/rc.wakeup ; --pid=exec
   root              422   0.0  0.0  2460656   1888   ??  S     2:45PM   0:00.17 /opt/local/sbin/sleepwatcher --verbose --sleep /opt/local/etc/rc.sleep --wakeup /opt/local/etc/rc.wakeup
   ```
6. Done!

Comment: I could use some review on this answer to ensure that I am activating the `.plist` thing correctly.

Comment: Followed it step-by-step, but it doesn't work for me. After sleep I unplug my external hard-drive, my MacBook5,3 wakes up and when I open the lid I get the unproperly ejected disk error.

Comment: This works for me, but only sometimes. Not sure why.

Comment: However, I also get the error "The disk was not ejected properly. If possible, always eject a disk before unplugging it or turning it off." while the machine is active, with the lid open, while I'm using it also. It seems that Mavericks has a bug with sporadic errors regarding USB-attached disks.

Comment: I'm still on ML, so it's not Mavericks specific, and I don't get the errors when the machine is active. I noticed that the .sleep script sometimes gets executed at wake, as if it doesn't get enough time to do so when it's going to sleep.

Comment: I have now disabled this as it doesn't seem to work consistently. In addition, I'm running into a Mavericks "sleep wake failure" crashes and I'm trying to see if I my sleepwatcher script was the culprit.

Comment: Also a good guide here:
http://damacy.net/post/9377132648/automatically-unmount-external-drives-on-sleep