# Is there a complete list of all hidden keyboard shortcuts in OSX?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I keep discovering keyboard shortcuts that are not listed anywhere under preferences. For example, I discovered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/143463/53888) that <kbd>⌥ ALT</kbd><kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> will eject all partitions on a disk when a partition is selected. How the heck do people find these shortcuts, and where can I find more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is a complete list, but this is a pretty good start from Apple:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236

Here is another link to an image of the shortcuts:

http://dashkards.com/img/dashkard-macosx-general.png

Comment: Unfortunately, neither shows ⌥⌘E! (Only the unmodified ⌘E is listed on the first link.)

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few keyboard shortcuts vary on different Macs, especially the laptops, so that is one good reason it is not easy to find a 100% complete list.

There is a [super in-depth guide, here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160306035620/https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/Keyboard.html) which was designed to show developers which shortcuts *not* to use, but seems to be the best go-to guide for the comprehensive ins-and-outs of keyboard shortcuts in OSX.

I'd also reccommend browsing around more on that same site (https://developer.apple.com), although I didn't see a definitive shortcut guide yet.

I've learned about many of the shortcut keys (including the ⌥-modifiers like the one you describe) by reading through the  Apple Pro Training Series books, by Peachpit Press.