# List of current set of all keyboard shortcuts in MacOS

Tags: macos, keyboard

Looking the web, I see a lot of articles and lists of various kinds of keyboard shortcuts in MacOS, whether how to create new ones, or on the difference between app-specific shortcuts and conflicting with global ones, and also [hidden ones](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232019/is-there-a-complete-list-of-all-hidden-keyboard-shortcuts-in-osx).

However, I want to find a place that shows:

1. Actual chosen/configured shortcuts/key-combinations in the current specific system
2. All shortcuted actions
3. Bonus: place to attach more than one shortcut combination to a specific action

For example, I found out that pressing CTRL+CMD+SPACE will pop the Emoji Viewer.
However, how can I change it to another combination of keypresses?
And, where can I find this shortcut listed somewhere?
Of course in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts, we can see various actions, their attached shortcut combinations, and ability to change them - but it shows only small part of available/shortcuted actions - which is not only annoying in terms of "what can I do" but also "how can I change the shortcut of what I know I can do".

Comment: The questions you ask have come up before and have been answered. Please check out the links listed on top of your question.

Comment: This is not an answer as I explained. Also I saw the links. I want a list of real local available links, maybe customized or modified, and not the official list from Apple's website

Comment: There is no central place for all of that. You can use https://www.mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet/ to see the currently* available key combos (*currently as in front application + systemwide).